# Android - Unable to set my imageView in custom adapter

Tags: android, imageview

i am trying to set my imageview based on string value. But the image never set. Please guide me if i did any wrong here. Thanks

here is my code :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getExpense expense = objects.get(position);
    EventController controller = new EventController(ctx);
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_expense_entry, parent, false);
    }
    TextView expenseId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.expenseId);
    expenseId.setText(expense.getExpenseId());
    TextView expenseName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.expenseName);
    expenseName.setText(expense.getExpenseName());
    TextView expenseQuantity = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.expenseQuantity);
    expenseQuantity.setText("Quantity : x" + expense.getExpenseQuantity());
    ImageView expenseImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivtype);
    String expenseType = controller.getExpenseType(expenseId.getText().toString());
    if (expenseType.equals("Food")){
        expenseImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.food);
    }
    else if (expenseType.equals("Beverage")){
        expenseImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.drink);
    }
    else if (expenseType.equals("Dessert")){
        expenseImage.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dessert));
    }
    else if (expenseType.equals("Set")){
        expenseImage.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.set));
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that your IF conditions are being met?  Did you step through in the debugger or you can add a log statement. ie: Log.i("DEBUG",expenseType).

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: @jasonflaherty no error found.

Comment: Did you add any of the log.i @wyoskibum noted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my above comment about ensuring that the IF conditons are being met.  You are using setImageResource which requires an integer and then you are using getDrawable. So your code isn't consistent.

Try this:

```
int resourceId = 0;

if (expenseType.equals("Food")){
    resourceId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("Food","drawable",ctx.getPackageName());
}
else if (expenseType.equals("Beverage")){
    resourceId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("drink","drawable",ctx.getPackageName());
}
else if (expenseType.equals("Dessert")){
    resourceId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("dessert","drawable",ctx.getPackageName());
}
else if (expenseType.equals("Set")){
    resourceId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("set","drawable",ctx.getPackageName());
}
expenseImage.setImageResource(resourceId);
```